# REST 4.0 & Ninject.Extensions.Wcf 2.3 NullReferenceException

Tags: web-services, rest, ninject, argumentnullexception

I am trying to make a simple REST Service with .NET 4.0 that uses ninject to inject any dependencies for the service.

This is what my service looks like currently:

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class ReportService
{
    private readonly ReportManager _reportManager;

    public ReportService(ReportManager reportManager)
    {
        _reportManager = reportManager;
    }

    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetReports", Method = "GET")]
    public List<ReportDTO> GetReports()
    {
        var reports = _reportManager.GetReports();
        return reports.ToList();
    }
}
```

This is my global.asax:

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes();
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("ReportService", new NinjectWebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ReportService)));
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return new StandardKernel(new ServiceModule());
    }
}
```

And my ServiceModule:

```
public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule 
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IFRSDbContext>().To<FRSDbContext>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<IReportRepository>().To<ReportRepository>();
        Bind<ReportManager>().ToSelf();
        Bind<ReportService>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following exception when I try to run my service:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +222
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9079228
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256
```

**EDIT**

I've updated to the most current version of my Service.. I am using Ninject 2.3 and Ninject.Extensions.Wcf 2.3 from [here](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=35322&buildTypeId=bt260&tab=buildResultsDiv) but am still having no luck.. what am I doing wrong? I've followed everything from the WcfTimeService example except that I am using a REST service and not a .svc Wcf service...

Comment: I am a bit confused about what version you are using since you have a `KernelContainer` and `NinjectWebServiceHostFactory`. The latest stable hadn't a `NinjectWebServiceHostFactory` and the current beta has no `KernelContainer`. Can you please clarify on this?

Comment: I am using version 2.2 which is the most recent release version available on github. I am currently trying to pull everything for the 2.3 version, but this has been a process.

Comment: So you are saying you are using 2.2 and some files from 2.3? This seems quite a mess to me and makes it nearly impossible to help you.

Comment: No I was using 2.2 but I've heard a lot of people have the same problem so I am trying to replace with 2.3 I am not mixing anything

Comment: 2.2 does not have NinjectWebServiceHostFactory. Where is this comming from?

Comment: I've cleaned up my example everything is the latest build of Ninject 2.3 now and I am getting a different exception for a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: @JohnSaunders not a duplicate since `NullReferenceException` was caused by third party library and not my own code.

Comment: @RemoGloor I was able to figure out the issue, I wasn't calling the Ninject base classes `Application_Start()` after I registered my routes. See my answer below. I thought you may want to add this to documentation for future reference.

Comment: True. I didn't notice the stack trace.

Comment: The latest Ninject source now has an example of using Ninject with the WCF REST Template.  I also posted an example of how to do this with 2.2 here: https://github.com/chafey/Ninject-2.2-Wcf-Rest-Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call Application_Start. Instead override OnApplicationStarted

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the sources of `Ninject.Web.Common` and `Ninject.Extensions.Wcf` I was able to track down the issue.

In order to get this to work without a *.svc file you need to call the `Application_Start()` method of the `NinjectHttpApplication` at the end of the `Application_Start()` in Global.asax.cs file, like so:

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes();
        Application_Start(); // added call
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("ReportService", new NinjectWebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ReportService)));
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return new StandardKernel(new ServiceModule());
    }
}
```

Without doing this, the Kernel never gets created and therefore that is what causes the `NullReferenceException`. After I did this everything started working perfectly.